# Knockout displays no data in the table when I use $.ajax to retrieve data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am having problems retrieving data via $ .ajax jquery and binds them into a table by knockout . When I run the code below , retrieving the data by $ .ajax , the table is empty . I could see that the data is in observableArray , but are not being linked. When change the $ .ajax by $ .getJSON , the table is filled .

Follow the code:

```js
var Papel = function (data) {
            var self = this;
            self.ID = data.ID;
            self.Nome = ko.observable(data.Nome);
            self.Descricao = ko.observable(data.Descricao);
        };

        var PapelViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            
            
            self.Papeis = ko.observableArray();
            self.Item = ko.observable();
            self.Erro = ko.observable();
            
            self.LoadPapeis = function(){
                //Quando troco por $.getJson funciona perfeitamente
                ajaxRequest("get", "home/list")
                    .done(function (datas) {
                        var mappedList = $.map(datas, function (item) { return new Papel(item) });
                        self.Papeis = mappedList;
                        
                    }).fail(function (a, b, c) { alert(c) });
            }
            self.LoadPapeis()
            
            function ajaxRequest(type, url, data) { // Ajax helper
                var options = {
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    cache: false,
                    type: type,
                    data: data ? data.toJson() : null
                };
                var antiForgeryToken = $("#antiForgeryToken").val();
                if (antiForgeryToken) {
                    options.headers = {
                        'RequestVerificationToken': antiForgeryToken
                    }
                }
                return $.ajax(url, options);
            }
            ;
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new PapelViewModel());
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="cont">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr><th>ID</th><th>Nome</th><th>Descricao</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: Papeis">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: ID"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Nome"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: Descricao"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table> 
        
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem has to do with the asynchronous call .

All help is welcome.

Thank you all

Comment: `self.Papeis = mappedList` should be `self.Papeis(mappedList)`